# Img size minimum 100% which ever is greater

Tags: css, image

I can't work this one out, but there is an example here http://www.e-qas.co.uk/

The background image will stretch and shrink but will not go small enough to show the white page, it always stays 100% one way or another.

All help appreciated

```
#main {

}

#pic {
    content:url("images/back1.jpg");

}
```

Comment: are you using <img> or <div> with background image

Comment: please add an example code as we don't know wether you need to use an image tag or a background image. Posting a link to a website isn't considered good practice as it can be deleted in the future and therefore make the question obsolete.

Comment: its in a div using a stylesheet

Comment: background-size: cover; does the same thing if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: That will shrink and keep ratio until it shows the white behind, i need it to stop at 100% height or width whichever is greater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) article. I prefer this way of getting a full-page background image:

```
html { 
   background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 

   -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
           background-size: cover;

    //Older IE versions
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

...but the article mentions many approaches which include cross-browser solutions. A demo can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php).

Comment: That seems to do it, I need to transfer that though in to css for a div instead of background of a html

Comment: If you check canIuse http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts `background-size` doesn't need any vendor prefixes : -webkit- was for android browser until 2.3 -o- was for opera 10.1 -moz- for FF 3.6 witch are all obsolete. You can consider removing them.